# How do I send Facebook notifications with Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

1 - FQL and Notifications are being deprecated.
2 - Posts/messages in graph are not the same as notifications.
3 - Notification using Graph is only included for "Games" and only for Desktop and not mobile.

So... how am I supposed to send notifications that works for all devices using Graph?

Anyone know?

Comment: Where did you see that notifications was deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are not depreciated, and are not just limited to Games (but the documentation does appear under Games). It's actually restricted to just Canvas apps. [This tutorial covers the use of notifications](https://www.webniraj.com/2012/09/28/facebook-api-app-notifications-api-for-facebook-canvas-apps/).

The best way for cross-device communication is to use emails. You can get the user's email address by requesting the `user_email` permission. You should make sure you allow users to unsubscribe from these emails and include the use of email addresses in your Application's privacy policy.

Comment: Thank you, i realize that now.

However, emails are not "best" way to communicate with people, we want people to our site, not reading emails...

And unfortunately the code on your site doesn't work, gives me (same problem I got to myself also before)
Warning: hash_hmac() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/u/u0336202/www/rent2friends.se/settings/php/base_facebook.php on line 942